# Selecting first anchor inside li element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML looks like this:

```
   <li class="li-top"><a class="top sub" href=#>Blah</a> .... </li>
```

What I am trying to do is to select the anchor tag, so I can change the color of the text ("Blah"). But here's the catch: I am using closest() because I am starting from a descendant of that li tag:

```
   $(this).closest('li.li-top');
```

How do I get that anchor tag from this starting point? I tried next(), each(), children(), etc. I can't get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're starting from one of the children, you might try:

```
$(this).parents('li.li-top').find('a:first');
```

I often go this way to find 'cousins once removed' in the DOM.

Answer (score 8):

This way probably:

```
$('li.li-top a:first')
```

Or:

```
$(this).find('li.li-top a:first')
```

Comment: Nope. I am using closest() and that selector doesn't work with closest(). It doesn't select the anchor. Thanks though.